# Using the nth item in a php array

Tags: php

I have created an array, as follows:

```
$results = array();
do {
  $results[] = $row_products;
} while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products));

print_r($results);
```

This prints out the array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
       [productName] => product1 
       ) 
[1] => Array ( 
       [productName] => product2 
       ) 
[2] => Array ( 
       [productName] => product3 
     )
```

I want to now use say the second item in the array in another mysql query.

But I cannot define it. I have tried

```
$results[1];
```

but this does not work.
So in effect, if I echo the second item, it would print 'product2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn the basics about arrays here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

You are using a nested array, so you have the access it like this:

```
echo $results[1]['productName'];
```

Another solution would be to use `$results[] = $row_products['productName'];` and then just echo `$results[1]`.

In addition, you should use a while loop instead of a do/while loop because $row_products does not seem to be defined for the first iteration.

```
while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) {
  $results[] = $row_products;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
echo $results[1]['productName'] ;
```

`$results[1]` is an array, If you want see the array `print_r($results[1]);`